# Angular Toaster not showing title or text

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, toast

I am using the toaster directive on my AngularJS web project.

Everything is configured as in the documentation; this is, on my view I have the container declared as follows.

```
<toaster-container toaster-options="{'time-out': 3000, 'close-button':true, 'animation-class': 'toast-top-right'}"></toaster-container>
```

I have injected the 'toaster' module globally on my **app.js** file and the 'toaster' service on my controller of interest.
On some action occurence I am calling

```
toaster.pop('success', "Comentario Actualizado", "");
```

The toast shows up on the view, at the correct spot, with the cancel button and the timeout that I configured of course. However, the toast is not showing any text along with it.
Anything I incorrectly implemented or anything I could be missing ?
Please help, I know the problem is super trivial but I truly don't understand why the expected behavior 
is not happening.

Thanks

Comment: It looks ok to me. check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4orym7by/1/).

Comment: Thanks, I see the fiddle works (why shouldn't it right?) However on the application I am working on it's not displaying the text , I suppose something else might be interfering...

Comment: If that's the case put the related code

Comment: Hello, the problem with my implementation is that I had the <toaster-container> inside a div, which has ng-show property. So that, apparently, by doing this the toast becomes buggy. I moved the container to another part of the file and is now working properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with Angular. Turned out I hadn't imported `BrowserAnimationsModule` at the top, as mentioned on [Getting Started With Default Configuration](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-toaster#getting-started-with-default-configuration---ngmodule-recommended) i.e.,

```
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

And then in the imports specifying:

```
imports: [BrowserAnimationsModule, ToasterModule.forRoot()]
```